# Angular.js. Wait for service before init application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular.js where I want the result from a service to be accessible all over the application from the start.

How can I achieve this?

My service:

```
export default function ConfigService() {
return ['$http', function($http) {

    this.config = function() {
        return $http({
            url: '../json/config.json',
            method: 'GET'
        });
    };
}];
}
```

App:

```
import services from './services';

angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'app.services'
]);

angular.module('app').config(routerConfig);

var app = angular.module('app.services', []);
app.service('ConfigService', ConfigService());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an abstract route in ui.router, which has a resolve. In this case all nested state will wait for resolving the resource. You can bind the result object of your config resource to `$rootScope`, so you can access it from anywhere.

Check these links below:

[Nested States & Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

[Resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)